# cannot start psql (postgres) on mac 10.8.5

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

Here is what I get when I try to access psql from console. I am using homebrew to run postgres.

```
atul-new-mac:sites user$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I checked the version by this:

```
atul-new-mac:sites user$ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

Here is the detail from the log file:

```
atul-new-mac:sites user$  tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
ERROR:  could not access status of transaction 0
DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_clog/0000": Permission denied.
LOG:  received smart shutdown request
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
PANIC:  could not open control file "global/pg_control": Permission denied
LOG:  checkpointer process (PID 381) was terminated by signal 6: Abort trap
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
LOG:  could not open temporary statistics file "pg_stat/global.tmp":            Permission denied
LOG:  abnormal database system shutdown
```

This is what I get when I try to start it manually:

```
atul-new-mac:postgres user$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l     /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
server starting
sh: /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log: Permission denied
```

Comment: I  noticed that there is some major permission issue. I have another rails app that uses "mysql" and that is behaving in the same manner. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: changing permission worked for mysql. But the same is not working for psql.

Comment: REinstalling postgres fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Just to note for someone having same problem like me: accidentally I have changed owner of the directory /var/lib/postgresql and caused same error, sudo chmod -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql  did trick

Answer (score 1):

Your log tells that your postgresql instance is having trouble with permissions (lines ERROR and PANIC) and reading other extracts you give, you may already have a postgresql instance running.

To check it, just do this command:

```
ps aux | grep -i "*postgres*"
```

You should see all postgresql processes running.

Try to stop all thoses processes either by using pg_ctl stop or if nothing happens and the processes are still there, then try to kill them (I presume you're on a development platform, so that should not cause a problem for others)

```
kill -9 <postgresID>
```

Then when all the postgresql processes have disappeared, then try to start postgresql. If you're still having a permission problem, [use lsof tool to see which process is locking your files](https://superuser.com/questions/97844/how-can-i-determine-what-process-has-a-file-open-in-linux).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I acataully just noticed that there is some major permission issue. I have another rails app that uses "mysql" and that is behaving in the same manner.    
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: i am trying to find the socket for mysql and getting this:                                           mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!